# Unable to resolve class EnableZuulProxy when starting customer-stores-ui/app.groovy using Spring Boot CLI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm quite new to Spring Boot and Spring Cloud and was trying to start the customer-stores example. I got the microservices running but each time when I try to start the the UI with

```
spring run app.groovy
```

I get the following exception:

```
startup failed:
file:/C:/Workspace/git/customers-stores/customers-stores-ui/app.groovy: 1: unable to     resolve class EnableZuulProxy ,  unable to find class for annotation
@ line 1, column 1.
@EnableZuulProxy
^

1 error
```

OK, this seems to be a missing dependency. But I don't have any clue of how to add this dependency. I tried with:

```
@Grab("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
```

But that doesn't change anything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some discussion [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/issues/1) tends to suggest there's a Windows platform issue with the "install" command, which is what the [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli) tells you to use.

This workaround works for me on Windows

```
$ gvm use springboot 1.1.5.RELEASE
$ cat grabber.groovy
@Grab('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:1.0.0.M1')
class App {}
$ spring grab grabber.groovy
$ find ./repository -name \*.jar -exec cp {} ~/.gvm/springboot/1.1.5.RELEASE/lib \;
```

then you should have all the dependencies installed.

The `@Grab` version will work if you a) add the starter for Zuul, not the bare core dependency, i.e.

```
@Grab("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
```

and b) explicitly add imports for all the classes you use.

Comment: Hi Dave, in the beginning I did not follow the instructions from README. Since this is only about the Spring Cloud CLI. Do I have to install the Cloud CLI Plugin before I can start the app? I tried but there really seems to be an issue. It seems that the spring install command does not install any resources.

Comment: Adding @Grab("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT") did not change anything.

Comment: I guess you need to add an import for the annotation class as well. It's probably better to try and fix the CLI plugin. You seem to be suffering from the same problem that the guy in github does (Windows). Can you use Ubuntu or MacOS to test until the install command is working on Windows?

Comment: It works with Ubuntu. There seem to be two problems with Windows. 1: The install command (install-0.0.2.jar) finds and lists the needed jars but does not copy anything to the lib folder. 2: The spring.bat file does not create the classpath correctly ->the main class cannot be found as soon as there is more then the spring boot jar in the lib folder.

Comment: Wow. OK those are unrelated bugs probably, and this isn't the best place to discuss that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62985/discussion-between-dave-syer-and-sebplorenz).